# Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: No such file or directory

Tags: apache, ubuntu, lamp, utorrent

I have just installed Ubuntu & starting with LAMP.

I installed it & it was working just fine till I installed uTorrent. Then after localhost was not opening & I tried with stopping apache & again restarting with it.

I used - sudo service apache2 restart

Now this error is coming - Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: No such file or directory

I checked there, there is no such file with this name.

Installed uTorrent is running on 8080 port...can it be problem ?

I really don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Is there an /etc/apache2/httpd.conf ?

If there is, have a look inside it and see what is being included i.e look for anything along the lines of:

```
Include /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Basically there error is being thrown because of an incorrect pathname in a `Include` directive in a conf file

Comment: I have removed apache. Is there any way to reset to factory setting where I started after install...
Many problem is coming...don't know why...
But I want to fight :)

Comment: When I am trying to install apache again it's coming :- debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable